# Overriding .net mvc framework validations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a popupeditform from a grid. I have applied validation rules to the binded model While testing I found that other than user specified validations, some framework generated errors are also coming up.

How can I override those messages

Eg :

This is what I give as validation

```
[Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Ratio should be between 0 and 100")] 
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Ratio is required")] 
public double Ratio {get; set; }
```

During run time I give value "2147483648" which is just above the maximum value. And I am getting error as "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32." If I give a value within permitted range say 2147483647 which is the margin value for int32 then my validation rules gets applied.

So my understaning is that the control comes first to the framework and shows framework validation message first.

In any way can I override the same ?

Comment: Using the overload of the `RangeAttribute` constructor that takes `double`s will improve that side of things a little, but you'd still have to deal with numbers outside the range for doubles...

Comment: you mentioned range validation and required. If the validation fails due to any other reason it will generated it's message related to error and not your escaped validation message.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an `Exception` message displayed as an `ErrorMessage`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay
Its not an exception. I am getting a framework generted message as "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned range validation and required validation.If the validation fails due to any other reason it will generated it's message related to error and not your escaped validation message.

you should limit the max length of input. if its double set max length accordingly and similarly for others. so your validation wont have bugs.

Comment: You mean i need to set the maximum no of digits permitted. The problem is; similar to ratio I have a price field. How could I limit the digits  here. Or is there any norms on this

Comment: When it comes to validation, you should either check whatever user enters or restrict the user to enter only a particular range of value. That's my idea.